# K running average Java

Tags: java, average

I am trying to make a method that takes an integer k and an array of integers as input and then returns the average of first k elements and then the average of next k elements and so on.. I do not know why my code is not working.

It seems like no one is getting my question. 
The question is to find the average of k elements at a time from an input array  which is xs.  And then form another array with values of averagek in it (average of k elements computed).

```
static int[] averagek(int k, int[] xs) {        
    int[] average = new int[xs.length-k+1]; 
    for(int i = 0; i < xs.length-k+1; i++) {            
        int sum = 0;                
        for (int j = i; j<i+k-1; j++) {            
            sum = sum + xs[j];
        }
        average[i] = (sum/k);
    }
    return average;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not working"? Are you getting an error? The wrong result?

Comment: What does *"my code isn't working"* mean? Are you getting an error, or is it behaving different to your expectations without throwing errors?

Comment: Holy whitespace.  And please fully explain what the problem is.

Comment: I am getting the wrong output

Comment: Beware of the fact that `xs.length-k+1` is different to `xs.length-(k+1)`. I don't know if that's your issue, because I don't have a clue what you're doing.

Comment: `for (int j = i; j<i+k-1; j++)` Say `i == 0` and `k == 1`, the loop body doesn't even execute once. So double-check your loop bounds.

Comment: Note: This is O(n^2) and you can do it O(n) with a single loop.

Answer (score 0):

At a glance, I see only one clear problem: that this:

```
        for (int j = i; j<i+k-1; j++) {
```

should be either this:

```
        for (int j = i; j < i + k; j++) {
```

or this:

```
        for (int j = i; j <= i + k - 1; j++) {
```

(The current version, with both a strict inequality `<` and `-1`, will miss the last element in the group to be averaged.)

But there may be other issues as well. I suggest the excellent blog post https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ to learn how to debug them.

I'll also note, by the way, that `int` may not be the appropriate data-type to represent the average of a group of integers; for example, the integer-arithmetic average of `2` and `3` is `2`, because there's no `2.5` in the integers. So you might want to switch to a `double[]`, and force floating-point arithmetic by writing `average[i] = (sum * 1.0 / k);`. (Up to you.)